# Articles With No Menu Item

Tags: articles, menu-item, layout

I was hoping somebody could explain this to me as I cannot seem to get my head around it.

I have a website with numerous articles and categories, all displayed at mydomain.com/blog

My homepage (mydomain.com) is set to `Articles » Category Blog`, and set to show one single article from the category `'Front Page'`. The problem is that whenever I click to read more about the article, it does infact show me more but stays on the homepage, i.e with all the various modules still in place.

Do I need to create a hidden menu and set this as my homepage, or am I way off?

Basically I want to be able to click an article title on my homepage and be taken to a new, fresh page displaying only that article. I know it's possible to use [Advanced Module Manager](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager) aswell, but I don't think it's necessary.

I know this must be pretty basic stuff, but I'd like to understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest some organizational restructure like below:

Instead of using a special Category named: "Front Page", use the "**Featured Articles**" option, to specify which articles you consider to appear in the home page.

Then assign your blog articles to their relative context category and not to a special one for the front-page.

For the blog, you can either use a **Category Blog Layout** item using the parent Blog category, and set it to display articles from all child categories, or if you like you could even create a hidden menu with **Blog Category Layout** menu-type for each blog-articles category you have. This will make your articles being displayed under the menu item of each category.

For the Front Page, use the **Featured Articles** menu-type, and choose the categories from which you want it to show featured articles and set it to display 1 leading article.

Hope it makes sense - let me know if you need further clarification.
It would also help, if you present your current articles organization structure (categories and child categories).

Comment: thanks @FFrewin that's exactly what I was looking for and has worked! I think I was just staring at the menu configs and my structure for so long that it stopped making sense. I have re-structured as you suggested (with Featured Articles on the front page) and works much better :)